# 404 error into cartoDB installation

Tags: carto, ubuntu

[image]

I am having 404 error into cartoDB installation. Need expert help to overcome the situations. http://104.238.134.159:3000/maps

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit Nachine

Answer (score 1):

Take a second look at '[running CartoDB section](http://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html#)'. You need to set up (and use) a subdomain.

Afterwards, "You should now be able to access `http://mysubdomain.localhost.lan:3000` in your browser and login with the password specified above."